# Comparing multiple columns in R

Tags: r, duplicates, comparison, multiple-columns

I would like to compare data in `R` across columns of different size.

This is my data set.

```
pp_value_1  pp_value_2  pp_value_3  pp_filename nn_value_1  nn_value_2  nn_value_3  nn_filename mm_value_1  mm_value_2  mm_value_3  mm_filename
17  73  53  CC3 5   29  53  AA2 11  56  34  AA2
129 516 34  BB5 44  217 42  BB1 36  190 39  BB1
107 436 44  AA3 29  147 53  CC7 30  155 31  CC1
57  244 53  BB6 21  108 53  BB2 14  77  61  BB4
57  227 29  AA1 21  104 39  AA6 9   48  44  BB6
80  318 47  AA2 18  89  47  CC3 37  200 44  DD3
128 529 56  BB4 43  222 54  CC1 36  202 50  CC3
31  127 53  CC1 7   38  53  DD4             
18  73  47  CC2
```

I used the `duplicated` function, appended the column with `TRUE` and `FALSE` results and then grepped results but it did not work. Here is my code:

```
v=duplicated(data$pp_filename, data$filename, data$filename)
b=cbind(data, dup=v)
dupl=(b[grep("FALSE", b$dup),])
```

And this is what I want to get (again in an appropriate format):

```
pp_value_1  pp_value_2  pp_value_3  pp_filename nn_value_1  nn_value_2  nn_value_3  nn_filename mm_value_1  mm_value_2  mm_value_3  mm_filename
17  73  53  CC3 18  89  47  CC3 11  56  34  AA2
80  318 47  AA2 43  222 54  CC1 30  155 31  CC1
31  127 53  CC1 5   29  53  AA2 36  202 50  CC3
```

Comment: Use the `{}` button on top of the edit window for code blocks (or code mark-down in general).

Comment: `FALSE` is a logical value (*not* a character string) in R. Why do you use `grep`? Is your data in a matrix of class character? That would be suboptimal. I'm not sure how your expected output is mapped to the input. Please tell us explicitly (in English, not using code). Also, read this FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a suggestion on the format of your data for the sake of easier manipulations.
I guess, a better format of your data would be:

```
spl = split.default(DF, substring(names(DF), 1, 2))
lDF = do.call(rbind, 
              lapply(seq_along(spl), 
                     function(i) 
                           setNames(cbind(names(spl)[i], 
                                          spl[[i]][complete.cases(spl[[i]]), ]), 
                                    c("type", gsub("^(.*?)_", "", names(spl[[i]]))))))
lDF
#   type value_1 value_2 value_3 filename
#1    mm      11      56      34      AA2
#2    mm      36     190      39      BB1
#3    mm      30     155      31      CC1
#4    mm      14      77      61      BB4
#5    mm       9      48      44      BB6
#6    mm      37     200      44      DD3
#7    mm      36     202      50      CC3
#8    nn       5      29      53      AA2
#9    nn      44     217      42      BB1
#....
```

Then, you can proceed (at least from what I understand from the question) with:

```
commons = Reduce(intersect, split(lDF$filename, lDF$type))
lDF[lDF$filename %in% commons, ]                                    
#   type value_1 value_2 value_3 filename
#1    mm      11      56      34      AA2
#3    mm      30     155      31      CC1
#7    mm      36     202      50      CC3
#8    nn       5      29      53      AA2
#13   nn      18      89      47      CC3
#14   nn      43     222      54      CC1
#16   pp      17      73      53      CC3
#21   pp      80     318      47      AA2
#23   pp      31     127      53      CC1
```

If you want the format you show, there are some workarounds you can come with. E.g.:

```
res = lDF[lDF$filename %in% commons, ]
tmp = split(res[-1], res[[1]])
do.call(cbind, 
        lapply(seq_along(tmp), 
               function(i) 
                  setNames(tmp[[i]], 
                           paste(names(tmp)[i], names(tmp[[i]]), sep = "_"))))
```

"DF" is:

```
DF = structure(list(pp_value_1 = c(17L, 129L, 107L, 57L, 57L, 80L, 
128L, 31L, 18L), pp_value_2 = c(73L, 516L, 436L, 244L, 227L, 
318L, 529L, 127L, 73L), pp_value_3 = c(53L, 34L, 44L, 53L, 29L, 
47L, 56L, 53L, 47L), pp_filename = structure(c(9L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("AA1", "AA2", "AA3", "BB4", "BB5", 
"BB6", "CC1", "CC2", "CC3"), class = "factor"), nn_value_1 = c(5L, 
44L, 29L, 21L, 21L, 18L, 43L, 7L, NA), nn_value_2 = c(29L, 217L, 
147L, 108L, 104L, 89L, 222L, 38L, NA), nn_value_3 = c(53L, 42L, 
53L, 53L, 39L, 47L, 54L, 53L, NA), nn_filename = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 8L, NA), .Label = c("AA2", "AA6", "BB1", 
"BB2", "CC1", "CC3", "CC7", "DD4"), class = "factor"), mm_value_1 = c(11L, 
36L, 30L, 14L, 9L, 37L, 36L, NA, NA), mm_value_2 = c(56L, 190L, 
155L, 77L, 48L, 200L, 202L, NA, NA), mm_value_3 = c(34L, 39L, 
31L, 61L, 44L, 44L, 50L, NA, NA), mm_filename = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 6L, NA, NA), .Label = c("AA2", "BB1", "BB4", 
"BB6", "CC1", "CC3", "DD3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("pp_value_1", 
"pp_value_2", "pp_value_3", "pp_filename", "nn_value_1", "nn_value_2", 
"nn_value_3", "nn_filename", "mm_value_1", "mm_value_2", "mm_value_3", 
"mm_filename"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is a very good suggestion with a new format. This does exactly what I wanted to do. I'm sorry my question was not clear enough. I need to learn how to use `seq_along` - a very useful function.

Answer (score 2):

To me, simple subscript operations seem more appropriate than grep.  But I still found an excuse to use grep anyway.

```
b <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
pp_value_1 pp_value_2  pp_value_3  pp_filename nn_value_1  nn_value_2  nn_value_3  nn_filename mm_value_1  mm_value_2  mm_value_3  mm_filename
17  73  53  CC3 5   29  53  AA2 11  56  34  AA2
129 516 34  BB5 44  217 42  BB1 36  190 39  BB1
107 436 44  AA3 29  147 53  CC7 30  155 31  CC1
57  244 53  BB6 21  108 53  BB2 14  77  61  BB4
57  227 29  AA1 21  104 39  AA6 9   48  44  BB6
80  318 47  AA2 18  89  47  CC3 37  200 44  DD3
128 529 56  BB4 43  222 54  CC1 36  202 50  CC3
31  127 53  CC1 7   38  53  DD4 18  73  47  CC2
")
# Any duplicated values among the "xx_filename" columns?
filenameCols <- grep("_filename", names(b))    
v <- apply(b[,filenameCols], 1, FUN = anyDuplicated) 
# Save rows with colliding xx_filename columns 
dupl <- b[v != 0,]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So what I wanted was to find duplicates between all `filename` columns. The solution you suggested does almost what I wanted as it shows that the names AA2 and CC3 occur in two `filename` columns although they occur in three. Also, it gives BB1, BB5 which actually do not occur in all three `filename` columns`.